# solr with typo3 not indexing

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

Namely, I have been involved in TYPO3. All status messages are green. Connection ok, template integrated correctly. Everything according to the instructions of the extension.
However, if I want to index the page, I get the error, see image.

Nothing is in the TYPO3 logs. Also devlog does not show me anything.
Someone more ideas? I have been searching for hours.

TYPO3 7.6.27
TYPO3 solr 6.5.1
solr-apache 6.6.3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohh0k.png)

Comment: What is your configuration of TYPO / configured URL to Solr? Does "Show error" on each item say anything more?

Answer (score 0):

The actual error can be found by clicking "Show error" next to one of the pages in the "Indexing Errors" part shown in your screenshot.

The most common problem I've seen is that the webserver can't reach itself using the domain used in TYPO3. If you have command line access, you could try getting the URL using curl or wget from the server.

Comment: Show error: Oh my god. So easy, I do not see it. Many Thanks.

Comment: But index fields is empty. :-(

Comment: 1331837081: RuntimeException: Failed indexing page Index Queue item 27572

Comment: Have you tried fetching the page with curl or wget on the server?

Comment: No why should I do that?

Comment: Because pages are rendered in the frontend they are indexed by fetching them using the URL. One of the most common reasons something goes wrong with page indexation is because the server can't fetch local content or doesn't know the domain points to itself. This can be checked by trying to fetch the page with curl or wget on the server manually.

Comment: So what exactly do you have to do a wget on?

Comment: It also has to run with the scheduler task. It does not do it.

Comment: The URL for a page that gives an error, so http://example.com/index.php?id=... The domain should be the first domain record for the site.

Comment: Resolving example.de (example.de)... IP
Connecting to example.de (example.de)|IP|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.php?id=1’

Comment: OK I will try. But the bugs are all just PHP warnings, no php fatal errors or similar.

Comment: Can you post your solr TypoScript configuration?

Comment: The only thing I can see that might cause problems is that the default port for solr 6.6.3 is 8983, not 8080. But that should show in the connection message. Do you have multiple solr versions running on that server?

Comment: sorry, copy & paste error. Of course, 8983 I have registered.
No. It is only as 6.6.3 on it.

Comment: added ... plugin.tx_solr.enabled = 1 ... plugin.tx_solr.enableDebugMode = 1 ... no result, also devlog ... no result

Comment: I also get no output (so no result found) in the frontend, if I'm looking for something.

Comment: enableDebugMode only adds debug information to search queries. For more logging when indexing you should use plugin.tx_solr.logging. See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/solr/6.5.1/Configuration/Reference/TxSolrLogging.html

Comment: You probably don't get any results because nothing has been indexed yet.

Comment: index Fields is filled. No idea what happened now. I just started the sheduler task again. http://localhost:8983/solr/typo3/select?q=test&qt=standard&fl=title works, but there is no output in the frontend.

Comment: If there's no output at all you might not have the templates configured correctly. If you get something like "No results found", you'll have to see what query is send (either as comments in the HTML source if enableDebugMode is on or in the solr logs on the server) and what the results are.